# Undefined symbols after installing new xcode 3.2.3 build

Tags: iphone, xcode, flurry

I want to move to the new XCode 3.2.3 GM Seed build for development, but when I bring up my project I get 'base sdk missing' because my project is set to use iPhone SDK 3.0.  If I change 'base SDK' to iPhone 3.2 or 4.0 and then compile I get a lot of errors that I don't understand.  I dumped a few of them below.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  Also, can someone confirm that if I choose 'base sdk' of iPhone 3.2 or 4.0 that I can still choose 'target device' of iPhone 3.0 and not force my customers to install the new SDK.  I really don't want to be the app that forces my customers to upgrade their OS.

Thanks!

Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAPI in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurrySession in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryHTTPEater in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryHTTPResponse in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPResponse.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryConnectionDelegate in libFlurry.a(FlurryConnectionDelegate.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAd in libFlurry.a(FlurryAd.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdParser in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSObject in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdImage in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImage.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdImpression in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImpression.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryPageViewDelegate in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdTheme in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdTheme.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdHook in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdHook.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdProperties in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdProperties.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryFileCache in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryEvent in libFlurry.a(FlurryEvent.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryProtocolData in libFlurry.a(FlurryProtocolData.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdAssignment in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAssignment.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdAppStoreConnectionDelegate in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAppStoreConnectionDelegate.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryHeartBeater in libFlurry.a(FlurryHeartBeater.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryImageCache in libFlurry.a(FlurryImageCache.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryUtil in libFlurry.a(FlurryUtil.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdNavigationDelegate in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdNavigationDelegate.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdLocation in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdLocation.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdDimension in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdDimension.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdTextStyle in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdTextStyle.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSFileManager", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSFileManager in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSFileManager in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPResponse.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryAd.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libFlurry.a(FlurryImageCache.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSError", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSError in libFlurry.a(FlurryUtil.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NFlurryAPI in NFlurryAPI.o
  ".objc_class_name_UIWindow", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIWindow in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSException", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libFlurry.a(FlurryUtil.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIColor", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIColor in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIColor in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIColor in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIColor in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NFlurryAPI in NFlurryAPI.o
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableSet", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableSet in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAssignment.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIFont", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIFont in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIFont in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasView.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIImage", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImage in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImage in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImage.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIApplication", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIApplication in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAppStoreConnectionDelegate.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UILabel", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UILabel in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasView.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIView", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdListView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdListView.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSTimer", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSTimer in libFlurry.a(FlurryHeartBeater.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableData", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableData in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableData in libFlurry.a(FlurryConnectionDelegate.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableData in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImpression.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableData in libFlurry.a(FlurryEvent.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSNumber", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImpression.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  "_objc_exception_match", referenced from:
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession dataForSessions:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UINavigationItem", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UINavigationItem in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIViewController", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIViewController in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      .objc_class_name_FlurryAdCanvasViewController in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libFlurry.a(FlurryImageCache.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdNavigationDelegate.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIScreen", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIScreen in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSURLCache", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURLCache in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNotificationCenter in libFlurry.a(FlurryHeartBeater.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSInvocation", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSInvocation in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSURL", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURL in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURL in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURL in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURL in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  "_objc_exception_extract", referenced from:
      +[FlurryAPI startSession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI startSession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI pauseSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI pauseSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI resumeSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI resumeSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:exception:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:exception:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:error:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:error:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageViews:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageViews:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageView] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageView] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setUserID:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setUserID:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setEventLoggingEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setEventLoggingEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setServerURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setServerURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setLandscapeCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setLandscapeCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppStoreURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppStoreURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppVersion:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppVersion:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setGender:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setGender:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAge:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAge:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI updateHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI updateHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI removeHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI removeHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI openCatalog:canvasOrientation:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI openCatalog:canvasOrientation:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession dataForSessions:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession dataForSessions:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurryAdParser oldInstance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      +[FlurryAdParser instance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      -[FlurryAdView initWithAd:hook:xLoc:yLoc:parent:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView initWithAd:hook:xLoc:yLoc:parent:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView refreshWithAd] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView refreshWithAd] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView updateToOrientation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView updateToOrientation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView touchesEnded:withEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView touchesEnded:withEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView checkBannerLocation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView checkBannerLocation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryAdCanvasViewController dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      -[FlurryAdCanvasViewController dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      +[FlurryFileCache createInstanceWithApiKey:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
      +[FlurryAdAssignment createInstance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAssignment.o)
      +[FlurryHeartBeater createAndStartInstance:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryHeartBeater.o)
      +[FlurryImageCache createInstanceWithFileCache:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryImageCache.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableURLRequest in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSRunLoop", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSRunLoop in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSKeyedUnarchiver", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSKeyedUnarchiver in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSKeyedUnarchiver in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSData", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSData in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSData in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDate", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libFlurry.a(FlurryHTTPEater.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdImpression.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDate in libFlurry.a(FlurryEvent.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIBarButtonItem", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIBarButtonItem in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSURLRequest", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURLRequest in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSURLRequest in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAppStoreConnectionDelegate.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIDevice", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIDevice in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIDevice in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
  ".objc_class_name_UIImageView", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImageView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImageView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@UIImageView in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasView.o)
  "_objc_exception_try_exit", referenced from:
      +[FlurryAPI startSession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI pauseSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI resumeSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:exception:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:error:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageViews:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageView] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setUserID:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setEventLoggingEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setServerURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setLandscapeCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppStoreURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppVersion:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setGender:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAge:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI updateHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI removeHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI openCatalog:canvasOrientation:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession dataForSessions:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession dataForSessions:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurryAdParser oldInstance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      +[FlurryAdParser instance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdParser.o)
      -[FlurryAdView initWithAd:hook:xLoc:yLoc:parent:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView refreshWithAd] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView updateToOrientation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView touchesEnded:withEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView checkBannerLocation] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryAdView dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdView.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didSelectViewController:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:willEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryPageViewDelegate tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryPageViewDelegate.o)
      -[FlurryAdCanvasViewController dealloc] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdCanvasViewController.o)
      +[FlurryFileCache createInstanceWithApiKey:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryFileCache.o)
      +[FlurryAdAssignment createInstance] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAdAssignment.o)
      +[FlurryHeartBeater createAndStartInstance:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryHeartBeater.o)
      +[FlurryImageCache createInstanceWithFileCache:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryImageCache.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDateFormatter", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDateFormatter in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
  "_objc_exception_try_enter", referenced from:
      +[FlurryAPI startSession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI startSession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI pauseSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI pauseSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI resumeSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI resumeSession] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logEvent:withParameters:timed:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI endTimedEvent:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:exception:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:exception:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:error:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI logError:message:error:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageViews:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageViews:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageView] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI countPageView] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setUserID:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setUserID:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setEventLoggingEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setEventLoggingEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setServerURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setServerURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setLandscapeCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setLandscapeCanvasURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppStoreURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppStoreURL:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppVersion:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppVersion:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setGender:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setGender:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAge:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAge:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI getHook:xLoc:yLoc:view:attachToView:orientation:canvasOrientation:autoRefresh:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI updateHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI updateHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI removeHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI removeHook:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI openCatalog:canvasOrientation:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI openCatalog:canvasOrientation:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurryAPI setAppCircleDelegate:] in libFlurry.a(FlurryAPI.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession createActiveFlurrySession:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)
      +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAds:] in libFlurry.a(FlurrySession.o)

Comment: OK, I think something is off on my machine...I had a colleague try this and it worked for him...maybe I will have to cleanup and re-pull the code fresh.
I am also at WWDC and it has been confirmed that I should choose the latest 'base SDK' and then choose the version to support through the 'target' setting.

Comment: OK, it looks like this is only a problem when I choose Simulator instead of Device.  That doesn't really help, but explains why it worked for my colleague.  I now have this working for Device on my computer as well, but that won't help me when I need to run the Simulator, which is very often, unless I set the project up to not use Flurry in Simulator mode. :(

I did stop by the tools Lab at WWDC. They told me that I need a new assembly file from Flurry that is compiled with the new SDK.  I can't imagine that I'm really the first one that has needed this...still think I am  missing something.

Comment: When you remove the old Flurry library and add the newer one, the Library Search Paths setting in the Target build information is APPENDED by the newer library path, not replaced by it. So for me, I was getting build errors because it was still searching the v2.2 directory BEFORE the v2.5 directory for the appropriate libraries.

Check that setting if you're still having build errors - it fixed things for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flurry posted v2.4 of their SDK today (or last night) seems to work fine in the simulator on xcode 3.2.3 with iOS 4.0...

Comment: I'm getting same problem with XCode 3.2.3, Flurry 2.5 (and 2.4), base SDK = 4.0, Deploy = 3.1.3.

Any more hints?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, but I think it is looking for iPhone OS 3.1.3 (which I no longer have installed).

```
ld: warning: directory '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-FlurryAPI in MoviePlayerAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(I would have added a comment to your comment as I know this isn't an answer but I can't)

---------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------

I emailed Flurry about this, and they just replied with an SDK which is compatible with iOS4 and 3.2 (and I'm assuming it will also work for you). If you want I can email the files to you, just send me a message at EDIT: Removed email

Comment: Yes, can you please email it to me at gary.mangum(at)gmail.com.  Thanks!  I emailed them as well, but did not get a response.

Comment: I am getting less linker errors, but still a few:
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_NFlurryAPI in NFlurryAPI.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlurryAPI", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_NFlurryAPI in NFlurryAPI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the Flurry lib and do a build clean all.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem for me but with foundation framework. The suggestion above about the target library path led me to a solution... in my case the 'framework search path' had an absolute reference to SDK 3.0 for some reason. I altered it to be a relative address i.e. "System/Library/Frameworks" and it linked properly in simulator!!